# Upload File on Azure unit test

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, unit-testing

I need to create some tests for upload image on azure and retrive the absolute URI .
Can you have any idea about can I create a unit/integration test for the following code?

```
public async Task < IActionResult > UploadFile(IFormFile files) {  
string systemFileName = files.FileName;  
string blobstorageconnection = _configuration.GetValue < string > ("BlobConnectionString");  
// Retrieve storage account from connection string.    
CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(blobstorageconnection);  
// Create the blob client.    
CloudBlobClient blobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();  
// Retrieve a reference to a container.    
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(_configuration.GetValue < string > ("BlobContainerName"));  

CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(systemFileName);  
await using(var data = files.OpenReadStream()) {  
    await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(data);  
}
return blockBlob.Uri.OriginalString;
```

Thanks guys so much

Best regards,
Belph

Comment: What do you want to test? Whether the azure SDK does the job correctly? That is Microsofts responsibility. If that is not the case, what logic do you want to test?

Comment: I want  to test if the code will return an URL from an azure storage account . That might be a good test I think :)

Comment: I don't think so, you will only test the methods inside the SDK, not your business logic...