# Unit test for retrive URL from AZURE

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, unit-testing

I want to upload an image to azure and to retrieve the absolut url .

And my method is something like that

```
    CloudStorageAccount storageacc = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);

CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageacc.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("myblob");
container.CreateIfNotExists();

CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("images");

using (var filestream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\11173.jpg"))
{
    blockBlob.UploadFromStream(filestream);
}
return blob.AbsoluteURI
```

Can suggest me how can I write a good code in XUNIT ?
Thank you !

Comment: Why ask the same question twice? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72913727/upload-file-on-azure-unit-test?noredirect=1#comment128785036_72913727

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you should test this part in unit tests, because unit tests uses in isolation of all external processes like database or object storage.
Maybe it would be better to test it in integration tests as a part of full business process with all dependencies